# Move cypress folder from the root of the project

Tags: testing, integration-testing, cypress

When I install and run cypress, it scaffolds a `cypress/` folder in the root of my project.

The problem is that all other test related data is stored in the `test/` folder. Is there an easy way to move it to `test/cypress` and configure cypress to look there?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Cypress has a few configuration options to specify custom folder structure.

For that you will need to have `cypress.json` file in the root of your project and specify the following structure there for cypress to properly pick up the files in `test/cypress/`:

```
{
  "fixturesFolder": "test/cypress/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "test/cypress/integration",
  "pluginsFile": "test/cypress/plugins/index.js",
  "screenshotsFolder": "test/cypress/screenshots",
  "videosFolder": "test/cypress/videos",
  "downloadsFolder": "test/cypress/downloads",
  "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/index.js"
}
```

More info in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files).

Comment: It still makes cypress to install in root directory of the project.

Comment: Hey Greg, where does my answer state that the cypress will install to another directory if you do this? You need to install it at root, move manually and reroute cypress in the config.

Comment: How can you do this in the latest version where the config is not a json but a ts file?

Comment: the answer was correct, but `integrationFolder` and `pluginsFile` were not present in the documentation. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders--Files

Answer (score 24):

If you want to directly specify from the command line which one to launch, you can use the `project` flag:

```
cypress open --project test
```

That's particularly useful if you have a monorepo with multiple cypress folders to test different apps.

[project option direct link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-project-lt-project-path-gt)

[example repo with usage](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-test-nested-projects#cypress-test-nested-projects)

[cypress run cli documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run)

Comment: Nice and clean!

Comment: Just a note, for me `cypress open --project test` had the expected result of running/placing the cypress tests in the `test/cypress` folder. When I ran the command as provided in this answer, it created additional tests at `test/cypress/cypress`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since nobody wants to configure every possible cypress folder in the config just because the main path is different from the default one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to move your Cypress "installation" directory which is being created when executing `cypress open` or `cypress run`, I suggest to follow this steps:

1) Run cypress with `--project <directory>` flag where *directory* is where you would like cypress to be installed. In my case I chose *test* directory:

`cypress open --project test`

2) Cypress should now create its startup directory in `/test/cypress` folder. Add your `cypress.json` file directly under `/test` (!) directory. If you are using TypeScript, you can add your `tsconfig.json` file there too.

3) In your `cypress.json` you can relatively configure your tests subdirectories. My file is:

```
{
  "projectId": "XXXXXX",
  "fixturesFolder": "cypress/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "ui",
  "screenshotsFolder": "cypress/screenshots",
  "videosFolder": "cypress/videos"
}
```

which means that my tests are under */test/ui* directory and the rest within /cypress.  I keep only *fixtures, plugins, screenshots, videos, support* dirs and the rest removed.

Works without issues. I hope that helps.

Comment: When you run the spec file individually how do you get it to detect?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress tests have the following file structure.

`cypress
├── fixtures
│   └── example.json
├── integration
│   └── example_spec.js
├── plugins
│   └── index.js
└── support
    ├── commands.js
    └── index.js
|
|__ cypress.json`

You have to move this file structure to `/test/`. By default `cypress.json` points to the immediate `cypress` folder.

Otherwise, You can define the configuration in `cypress.json` file as @GlebKost mentioned in above answer.