# Move cypress folder ts config

Tags: reactjs, configuration, cypress

I wanted to move the cypress folder inside the test folder but all the resources are for the json config file. Cypress is updated and now uses a config.ts file and I am not able to add all the folder directories in it to get it working.

Found: [Move cypress folder from the root of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196173/move-cypress-folder-from-the-root-of-the-project) but it uses json config.

I do not want to create a cypress with Project "test".

Help appreciated!

Comment: please specify which folders you could not find

Answer (score 1):

With Cypress now using a `cypress.config.ts` file, they've eliminated `testFolders` as a config option. Instead they suggest using the [`specPattern` property.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e)

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    ... other properties
    specPattern: '/path/to/test/files/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
  }
});
```

By default, `specPattern` looks for `cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` for e2e tests (and  `**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` for component (but excluding anything matching the e2e values.))

Answer (score 0):

In the linked question this is the Cypress v9 config given by Gleb:

```js
{
  "fixturesFolder": "test/cypress/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "test/cypress/integration",
  "pluginsFile": "test/cypress/plugins/index.js",
  "screenshotsFolder": "test/cypress/screenshots",
  "videosFolder": "test/cypress/videos",
  "downloadsFolder": "test/cypress/downloads",
  "supportFile": "test/cypress/support/index.js"
}
```

The equivalent in Cypress v10 would be:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({

  // same options as Cypress v9
  fixturesFolder: 'test/cypress/fixtures',
  screenshotsFolder: 'test/cypress/screenshots',
  videosFolder: 'test/cypress/videos',
  downloadsFolder: 'test/cypress/downloads',

  // these options are specific for e2e test
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',

    supportFile: 'test/cypress/support/e2e.js',

    // import a legacy pluginsFile that has moved under /test folder
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./test/cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },

    // wildcard pattern for all tests 
    specPattern: 'test/cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',

    // OR named list of tests
    specPattern: [
      test/cypress/e2e/test1.cy.js,
      test/cypress/e2e/test2.cy.js,
    ]
  }
})
```